# Could not find stored procedure DataRefresh.GetSchedule error when managing SharePoint 2016 PowerPivot data refresh schedules

Tags: powerpivot

Upgrading from SharePoint 2013 to 2016 and ReportingServices/PowerPivot (SharePoint integration), when users attempt to modify an existing PowerPivot schedule, [image: Unable update PowerPivot Schedule]

Reviewing the SharePoint logs, there is an error Could not find stored procedure 'DataRefresh.GetSchedule'
[image: Missing DataRefresh.GetSchedule]

Am I missing a patch? 
Current configuration:

SharePoint 2016 v. 16.0.4351.1000

SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2) (KB4340355) - 13.0.513.0

I can replicate the behavior on existing and new Excel documents (creating a new schedule seems to work and clearing the file's Properties didn't make a difference)

Answer (score 1):

The `[DataRefresh].[GetSchedule]` is already removed in SP 2013 as mentioned at the official Microsoft article [Changes to PowerPivot Service application database in SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2756665/changes-to-powerpivot-service-application-database-in-sharepoint-serve?wa=wsignin1.0)

[image]

---

I think you got this error in SP 2016 for old files because you didn't apply the [Hot fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2927748/fix-powerpivot-workbook-cannot-do-data-refresh-in-sharepoint-2013-afte) on the SharePoint 2013 before migration.

**The available workarounds**

- Recreate the old schedule again as a fresh and new schedule on the SharePoint 2016 that should be working properly as you confirmed!
- Or Open a ticket with Microsoft, maybe they have easiest solutions!

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes, I've read the article and this is a new SharePoint 2016+PowerPivot environment and able to reproduce the problem with a new Excel document.  Our DBAs will not allow a SQL Server 2012 patch on SQL Server 2016 and those stored procedures listed do not exist on the old SharePoint+SQL server backend.  I assume the hotfix has already been applied since SharePoint 2013 is working fine.

Comment: Ran a SQL Server trace and the SharePoint PowerPivot service is executing the GetSchedule stored procedure, but right after is executing the GetRefreshSchedule stored proc.  No errors and if I run the command in SSMS, the data is returned, I assume, as expected.  Some sort of bug...oops..undocumented feature in the service/UI?  Opened a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Actually, it's a strange issue, in the documentation, Microsoft said the stored procedures already removed!  I am looking forward to hearing from you after Microsoft reply!

Comment: So far the techs are all focused on the warning (the red text in the first screenshot) and not the ULS logs or any of the other data points I've provided. I'm not inspired with confidence right now.

Comment: After about two weeks with numerous remote sessions with Microsoft, the problem still persists.  We have given up hope on a resolution.  I suspect its a bug in the SharePoint UI+service and unlikely this will be put on anyone's priority list to fix.